# What does Diglett scratch with?

Tags: pokemon-red-blue-yellow-green

Diglett and Dugtrio learn Scratch and Slash in gen 1. What should we suppose they are slashing with? Do the parts of them inside the hole look like little moles? Is there some depiction in the anime or otherwise of the bit of Diglett that's inside the hole?

If I was on the dev team I might have gone for Headbutt over Slash. They do appear to be mostly head, after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](https://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Diglett_(Pok%C3%A9mon)#Trivia):

> Its ability to learn moves like Scratch and Slash imply it has claws on its hands and feet.

Also, a Diglett in *Pokémon Mystery Dungeon: Red/Blue Rescue Team* mentions that it has feet, though their size and appearance are unknown.

Comment: I prefer [this](https://i.imgur.com/tRZyfDl.jpg) fan-made concept than accepting that Diglett has feet :)

Comment: @Wondercricket in that case it should have Bite or Crunch :D

Comment: Seems more like a kid-friendly "graboid" from the movie Tremors. Little nugget body would be covered in hair-like tiny barbs that each only move a little but when moving in waves would give it insane speed capability. Then the Alolan version would use it's hair like the big ones use their tongues on Tremors.

Comment: @Wondercricket that picture is amazing

Comment: I'm surprised a link to an image with a tooth was linked before showing a fan-made image with the rest of Diglett's body :P: https://i.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/original/001/169/149/137.png

Comment: @MBorg never seen this, it's kinda cute